# How to recover the original file directory after a loop?

Tags: r

I'm new to R language. Currently working on function that require setting the directory first. Let's say my orignial directory is "C:/Users/DS/Desktop/LLLRRR/coursera/Coursera". After function("specdata",...), it will set directory to "C:/Users/DS/Desktop/LLLRRR/coursera/Coursera/specdata". Is there any way I can recover to the original directory at the end of the loop?

My current solution is adding a setwd("C:/Users/DS/Desktop/LLLRRR/coursera/Coursera") at the end of the loop.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id=1:332){
    path<-paste(getwd(),directory,sep="/")
    setwd(path)
    data<-data.frame()
    if(id<10){
      readfile<-paste("00",id,".csv",sep="")
      dt<-read.csv(readfile)
      data<-rbind(data,dt)
    }else if(id>9&id<100){
      readfile<-paste("0",id,".csv",sep="")
      dt<-read.csv(readfile)
      data<-rbind(data,dt)
    }else{
      readfile<-paste(id,".csv",sep="")
      dt<-read.csv(readfile)
      data<-rbind(data,dt)
    }
    return(mean(data[,pollutant], na.rm = T))
}
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23)
```

"""

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23)
[1] 1.280833

getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/DS/Desktop/LLLRRR/coursera/Coursera/specdata"
```

It remains the new directory
Is there a better way to recover the original directory?
"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assign the original directory to an identifier before setting it with current directory and at the end, return a `list`

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id=1:332){
    origdir <- getwd() # modified
    path<-paste(origdir,directory,sep="/")
    setwd(path)
    data<-data.frame()
    if(id<10){
      readfile<-paste("00",id,".csv",sep="")
      dt<-read.csv(readfile)
      data<-rbind(data,dt)
    }else if(id>9&id<100){
      readfile<-paste("0",id,".csv",sep="")
      dt<-read.csv(readfile)
      data<-rbind(data,dt)
    }else{
      readfile<-paste(id,".csv",sep="")
      dt<-read.csv(readfile)
      data<-rbind(data,dt)
    }

    list(Mean = mean(data[,pollutant], na.rm = TRUE), Dir = origdir) # modified
}
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for that!